# RecordNotFound returns false when there are no rows

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am having a problem with [this library](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.RecordNotFound) because this function returns false even when the given input is not in the database, when in fact it should return true.

```
type User struct {
    ID          uint      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Username    string    `json:",omitempty"`
    Password    string    `json:",omitempty"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:",omitempty"`
}

b, err := db.Con()
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}

defer db.Close()

// We want an empty struct
// Otherwise it will trigger the unique key constraint
user := []User{}

// Check if the username is taken
// BUX, MUST FIX: This always returns false for some reason
if db.Where(&User{Username: "MyUsername"}).Find(&user).RecordNotFound() == false {
    fmt.Println("Username found")
}
```

Why is it always returning false, even when the string is empty?

Comment: From the docs of the error: *"ErrRecordNotFound record not found error, happens when only haven't find any matched data when looking up with a struct, **finding a slice won't return this error**"* (emphasis mine) [link](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#pkg-variables)

Comment: Hey @Jeffrey, do you expect to have multiple users with the same username in your database (a bad idea)?

Comment: @mkopriva "finding a slice won't return this error". Thank you for this info, this is absolutely crucial when using Gorm and can lead to so many bugs!

Answer (score 11):

Looks like `.RecordNotFound(`) is removed from the SDK for some reason.

Now use this for handling record not found errors

```
dbRresult := userHandler.db.Where("email = ?", email).First(&user)
if errors.Is(dbRresult.Error, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
    // handle record not found
}
```

Comment: It prints an error to the console when no record is found. How can I avoid this ?

Comment: It's not working as expected now.
dbRresult.Error and gorm.ErrRecordNotFound both are of errorString but Is() returning false.

Answer (score 6):

The following code should work as you expect it:

```
// We want an empty struct
user := User{} // We expect to have one (or no) user returned.

// Check if the username is taken
// Notice the use of First() instead of Find()
if !db.Where("username = ?", "MyUsername").First(&user).RecordNotFound() {
    fmt.Println("Username found, here's the user:", user)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Username not found")
}
```

As [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) already mentioned the `ErrRecordNotFound` will not trigger when you're working with slices.

Since you don't need slices *(your username should be unique)* we can:

1. Reference **not a slice of Users but a single User** `User{}` instead of `[]User{}`.
2. Use `gorms` `First()` method instead of `Find()`.

Comment: @Jeffrey Anderson, since you're new. If you find this answer acceptable, and it has solved your problem. Make sure you [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), this way other users can find a solution more easily.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about that. It was still returning user found if the string was empty but I managed to fix that myself!

Comment: There is just one problem with this, it is not case sensitive. If user "MyUser" exists but the input is "myUser", then it will return true. I'm also doing the same for checking emails, and emails MUST be case sensitive, so I can't `ToLower()` them. How can this be fixed?

Comment: .RecordNotFound()  has been removed from Gorm.

Comment: Also First() prints an error to console when the record is not found.

Comment: please add .Error() like this `dbRresult.Error.Error() == gorm.ErrRecordNotFound.Error()`

Answer (score 2):

**The below code does works, enjoy.**

```
id := c.Params("id")
address := &Address{}
result := db.Where("id = ?", id).Limit(1).Find(&address)
if result.RowsAffected == 0 {
    fmt.Println("ERROR : no row found on this id.")
    // redirect
    return c.Redirect("/")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the type of both is not same, so you can add .Error() to make sure they are string

```
dbRresult := userHandler.db.Where("email = ?", email).First(&user)
if dbRresult.Error.Error() == gorm.ErrRecordNotFound.Error() {
    // handle record not found
}
```